# Is there any way of protecting a variable for being modified at runtime in C?

Tags: c, variables, constants

I was wondering if there is any way of protecting a variable for being modified once initialized (something like "constantize" a variable at runtime ). For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int v, op;
    scanf( "%d", &op );
    if( op == 0 )
        v = 1;
    else
        v = 2;
// here transform v to a constant...
    .
    .
// ...and that any attempt to modify v yields to an error.
    .
    .
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: C borrowed C++ `const` keyword.

Comment: @DavidHaim C specified `const` keyword before C++ was invented

Comment: One can protect heap memory like in this [example](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the result of the input be `const` like this:

```
int func()
{
    int op = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &op );
    if( op == 0 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}

int main()
{
    const int v = func();
    // ...
}
```

NB. Of course, there is no way to prevent undefined behaviour happening later in the program which appears to change `v` (since undefined behaviour can, by definition, have any effect).

Comment: I tested your code. And it works fine. So the instruction                            const int v = func();      is executed in runtime not in compile time. If a line attempting to modify v is added a error is reported (compiling with gcc).

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Factor your code:

**foo.h:**

```
void do_something(int arg);
```

**foo.c:**

```
#include "foo.h"

void do_something(int arg)
{
    // implement
    //
    // Here "arg" is completely under your control.
}
```

**foo_test.c:**

```
#include "foo.h"

// add unit tests for do_something
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    int op;
    if (scanf("%d", &op) != 1) { abort(); }

    do_something(op == 0 ? 1 : 2);
}
```

It is now completely clear from the code that the function argument of `do_something` is private and local to the function and cannot be affected by anything above the call.

Comment: @Olaf It's not "missing" rather it's not needed. `extern` is optional for function declarations and have external linkage by default, if no storage class is specified.

Comment: @Olaf I don't see why. `foo.h` is included in `main.c` which will provide the prototype for `do_something()` (and is external by default) and `foo_test.c` will provide the definition.

Comment: @Olaf If you have a declaration with external linkage first and then with internal linkage then it's *undefined behaviour*. I don't see what, the presense of `extern` keyword, would solve there.

Comment: @Olaf: Could you please discuss the merits of `extern` elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent a global variable from being modified after initialization is declaring it `const`:

```
const int i = 5;
```

Hoever, as shown above, this requires it to be initialized with the definition.  There is no way of initialize it from program code or using other than a *constant expression* which is evaluated at compile-time.

Note that while you *can* cast the const away, this results in *undefined bahaviour* and very likely leads to problems as `const` variables might be put into a read-only memory area of your program.

If you *do* need access control to such a variable, you would have to put it either as `static` into a function (with initialization on first call), or - better a seperate module/compilation unit (also as `static`). Use explicit setter/getter function on this then:

```
"wrapper.h":

#ifndef WRAPPER_H
#define WRAPPER_H

extern void set_once(int v);
extern int get_value(void);

#endif
```

---

```
"wrapper.c":

#include <stdbool.h>
#include "wrapper.h"

static struct {
    bool is_set;    // guaranteed false on startup
    int value;
} my_var;

void set_once(int v)
{
    if ( !my_var.is_set )
        my_var.value = v;
    else
        ; // report an error, e.g. abort()
}

int get_value(void)
{
    if ( !my_var.is_set )
        return my_var.value;
    // report an error, e.g. abort()
}
```

---

```
"main.c"

#include "wrapper.h"

int main(void)
{
    set_once(5);
    int i = get_value();
}
```

This way you will can get a runtime error if you use the value uninitialized or tries to set it more than once. Note the flag relies on global variables to be initialized to 0 (which is guaranteed to evaluate `false`).
Although you might just ignore multiple sets, is is good practice to catch and report, at least during debugging/testing (e.g. using `assert`).

**Edit:**

The approach above is for global variables. If multiple variables are to be protected, it can be modified such as the functions take a pointer to the struct. If different types are to be used, pack the flag into its own struct and add that as the first anonymous field to one struct type for each type to be protected. If gcc-extensions are available&allowed, have a look at `-fplan9-extensions`. Using opaque pointers can avoid unintended external modifications.

For local variables, however, use @MattMcNabb's version.

Comment: take a look at the code of Matt McNabb please. There the value of v is assigned at runtime. Is there any compile option that detects it as an error? or isn't there no error at all?

Comment: @jruiz: I added the word "global" to my answer. Matt's answer actually _does_ work, but onlyfor an `auto` variable, not even a local `static`. I did presume it should be a global (compilation unit or program scope), so I provided a more general approach. It you're just up for an `auto`, his approach will be better for you (well, you also could pass a pointer to all called functions, but that will very quickly become unmanageable.

Comment: @jruiz: You can extend this approach to a more general version by just passing pointers to such variables to the functions, if you have multiple such variables. There is no actual need to have one set per variable. If gcc extensions are allowed, this can be even done for different types (almost) without type casts.

Comment: Thanks for you solution, but When I compile your code with -pedantic flag the compiler report the error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations. Another detail is that in you code my_var is a global variable, which I am avoiding.

Comment: @jruiz: Well, I did not compiler. There might be typos, just tell me where, I will correct them. For C90: The code uses ´stdbool.h` which became standard with C99. I normally do not care about C90 support (If required, I would use C11). However, it is just the example im `main()`. Just move the definition on to of the block and leave the assignment where it is. After all it is just an example. Regarding the global: I allready commented on that in my previous comment. Note that the variable only has CU-scope, not program-global.

Comment: I added the -std=c99 flag (thank you). (I did not realized of any typos)

Comment: @jruiz: That was more a disclaimer. If that helped, you know, please think of ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No, never.

You could make it `const`, but that's more of a light hint and can be cast away with barely any effort. Besides if you have a pointer to something you can always change it by direct memory access.

You could also hide it inside a class that manages write access to it, but you're in the same situation as the first case -- you have a pointer to it.

Comment: It's more than an hint, the object can then be put in non-modifiable memory and casting away the qualifier makes your program not strictly conforming.

Comment: `const` is a promise by the programmer, that value will not be changed, which is more than just a hint. Compiler's optimizer will take your word for it, and may generate code which assumes the value does not change.

Comment: @Blindy, did you see the code sent by Matt McNabb. Do you see any error there?

Comment: @jruiz, no error, but you're misinterpretting it. You can easily take the pointer of `v` (or even just the raw value of `esp`/`rsp` and subtract 4) and change it without ever changing the definition from `const` (or casting it away, which also works). That's what all of those unnamed aliasing warnings that are plastered all over gcc/msvc/icc optimization options are about. Contrast this to C# for example, where `const` variables are never even written to code, their literal value is replaced into opcodes using them.

Comment: I maintain that in comparison to what most people would expect from `const`, it's a mild hint implementations aren't even required to adhere to (besides the obvious refusal to change directly variables that actually have the `const` modifier attached to them), and in fact they actually drop it as soon as you do something funky with it, like use the `&` operator.

Comment: (I would suggest to you the following, just for you not to make this same mistake on another occasion, as do not know how I'm interpreting the code, you make a mistake in saying that I'm misinterpreting it)